# Elastic Search select doc only if all the values exist in the array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a bunch of products in my index and each product has this document structure

```
{
  "id": 59342,
  "days": [
    {
      "date":  "2018-08-14",
      "rate": 101.00
    } 
    , 
    {
      "date":  "2018-08-15",
      "rate": 200.00
    }
    , 
    {
      "date":  "2018-08-18",
      "rate": 200.00
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to get this document only if the `days` array contains all the dates between `2018-08-14` to `2018-08-16`. I have tried a couple of solutions but none have worked. Here is what I have so far

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "days",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "days.date": "2018-08-14"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "days.date": "2018-08-15"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "days.date": "2018-08-16"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the mapping data of the products

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "products": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "days": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "date": {
              "type": "date"
            },
            "rate": {
              "type": "double"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```